# SO_TIMESTAMPING: Which timestamp is used if we read multiple packets at once?

Tags: linux, networking, timestamps

Given Linux is used and packet timestamping is enabled with `SO_TIMESTAMPING` for a TCP socket and we read now some data, what timestamp will be reported if the byte-stream which we read was merged out of multiple TCP packets (which each have different timestamps)?

I assume the newest one, but maybe there is some more magic involved in this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would say the answer is in paragraph 1.4 of https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot. The answer was indeed there and it seems to be the case that the timestamp describes the moment when all the data was in the kernel buffer.

Comment: There is additional context (including the multiple flags to pass to this socket option) that you would know (and that I don't). Maybe you could answer your own question so it won't stay "unsolved"?